# Showing list of items including item details on same page in Django

Tags: django

In a Django v3.x app I would like to display a list of uploaded file names (e.g. images) in the left hand side of the screen. When a user clicks on one of those, I'd like to display the actual file/image on the right hand side of the screen. I am still new to Django and have used both ListView and DetailView separately, but not in such a combination. I'm not sure how this can be achieved.

Using a little Bootstrap magic, I can create a split screen easily. Hence, my template would look somehow like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 left">
  {% for image in images %}
     <div class="card">
       <h4>{{ image.url }}</h4>
       <a href="{{ image.url }}">View</a>
     </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 right">
    {# TODO: When the user clicks on the View url above, then I'd
    like to load the actual image here on the right hand side of the
    screen inside this div-tag. #}
  </div>
</div>
```

Question 1: How can I achieve loading a selected image from a list? Can I still use ListView and DetailView, or do I need to write my own View logic?

Question 2: Ideally, I'd like to NOT re-send the whole page from the server to the client, because the list of images in the lefthand-side could potentially be long and require pagination. So, when the user clicks View, then, ideally, I'd like to load only the document from the server. Is this somehow feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have made a sample code and you can refer to it and get some idea.

```
  <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
  <div id="carousel-thumb" class="carousel slide carousel-fade carousel-thumbnails" 
data-ride="carousel">
<!--Slides-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      {% for latest in latest_course %}
      <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}active{% endif %}">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{latest.poster.url}}" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>


<!--/.Slides-->
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <ol class="slider_list">
    {% for latest in latest_course %}
      <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="{{forloop.counter0}}" 
       class="active"> <img class="img-thumbnail" width="100px" height=100px src=" 
         {{latest.poster.url}}"
        class="img-fluid"></li>

  {% endfor %}
  </ol>

</div>
```

and the output looks like this
[image]

Here, you can see the list on the right side and when you select an item the selected item loads in the left side. This way you can style your template the way you want.

Comment: Ah, awesome! I was not aware that there exists such a thing as `{% forloop.counter %}`. I assume that clicking an image will do a complete server roundtrip though, is that right?

Comment: yea, you get whatever image is clicked on the left.

Answer (score 0):

basically you want to show the selected item from the list on the other side like a slideshow

Comment: You can check this url:  https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/KG9KW. I think this is what you want and u can get some idea on how to do it

Comment: Well, thanks for the suggestion, that's pretty much what I want, but I'd like to do this in Django. The image files are not necessarily static content in my file system, but potentially could be loaded from a database. Of course, I could use Javascript to make a call to the server, but that would break the whole idea of using Django in the first place.